# For which values of k the set is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For which values of $k$ the set is linearly independent

$$S = \left\lbrace \begin{bmatrix} k \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ k - 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ k \\ 3 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right\rbrace?$$
Please explain to me how this should be solved and how can I get the values of $k$? The question is really fuzzy to me.

Comment: Is the concept of linear independence fuzzy to you? Because the problem above is fuzzy if and only if this concept is fuzzy, I would think.

Comment: I suppose for this problem it would suffice to do $det(S) \ne 0$.

Comment: Hi Abdullah. It's generally preferred if you avoid links to images wherever possible. I've formatted the question with MathJax. Feel free to look at the code for doing so (by pressing edit) to see how I've done this. The `\left` and `\right` tags are not strictly necessary, and are there to fit the braces around the tall column vectors.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do we check for linear dependence algorithmically? Set up a matrix with the vectors of interest as rows or columns. Using yours as columns we compute 
$$
\det\left (\begin{bmatrix}k&2&2&1\\1&k&0&0\\2&3&1&0\\k-1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix} \right)\\
\stackrel{\text{expansion by minors along bottom row}}{=}(1-k)\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}2&2&1\\
k&0&0\\
3&1&0 \end{bmatrix}\right)\\
\stackrel{\text{expansion by minors along third column}}{=}(1-k)\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
k&0\\3&1 \end{bmatrix}\right)\\=(1-k)k
$$
when this determinant vanishes at $k=0$ and $k=1$, the set is dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If necessary before to perform the calculationnof the determinant you could proceed also with some Row/Columns linear combination in order to simplify the calculation.